# Can we play sounds in the background at a particular intervals in the iPhone app?

Tags: ios, avplayer, background-music

In my app I need to play some sounds like beeps at a particular intervals of time (May not be uniform intervals), even the app is in the background. I have gone through the google and many suggested to use  AV Foundation’s AVPlayer. I have gone through the following tutorial also.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

This tutorial explains how to play a queue of items.

But in my app there will not be any continuous music. Just we need to play some sounds while the app in foreground or background.

Simply i need to play sounds as RunKeeper does.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scheduling a local notification and providing a custom sound: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html. This will also display an alert in notification centre / lock screen though.